# what will the best data storage?

Tags: android, database, cocos2d-iphone, andengine

i am developing a game in android .i want to store and retrieve the highest score .
The number of records in higher score will be 10.
So please tell me the best option(SQLlite , shared preferences etc) for store it .

Comment: Use SQLite it will be better option. Than shared preference for your requirement...

Comment: example for creating SQLite http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/

Comment: sharedpref is much quicker to setup. sqlite is an overkill for that use. I would put highscores in a jsonarray and store it as a String.

Comment: @RajaReddyPolamReddy - could you provide any reasons you feel SQLite is better?

Answer (score 2):

Use SharedPreferences because you have a fixed size (10) and it is simple to set up.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt(SCORE_1, 500);
editor.putInt(SCORE_2, 200);
editor.putInt(SCORE_3, 100);
editor.putInt(SCORE_4, 0);
...
editor.commit();
```

If you have dynamic data with different tables and a lot more data use a sqlite database.

See [Android Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for further details.

Comment: I use shared preferences for a user's individual high scores. I also use Google Play Game Services leaderboards.